# add_timer causes kernel stack dump for multiple PCI boards

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

We are using FPGA cards with PCI express drivers to move data around with DMA engines. This all works fine for a single card in a machine, however with two cards it fails. As an initial investigation, I have narrowed an error down to the add_timer function that is used to set up the polling mechanism. When insmod adds the driver modules, a stack trace is produced as the poll_timer routine is the same for both instances. The code has been reduced to

```
static int  dat_probe(struct pci_dev *pdev, const struct pci_device_id *ent)
{
    struct timer_list * timer = &poll_timer;
    int i;

    /* Start polling routine */
    log_normal(KERN_INFO "DEBUG ADD TIMER: Starting poll routine with %x\n", pdev);
    init_timer(timer);

    // random number added so that expires value is different for both instances of timer
    get_random_bytes(&i, 1);
    timer->expires=jiffies+HZ+i;
    timer->data=(unsigned long) pdev;
    timer->function = poll_routine;

    log_verbose("DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer expires %x\n", timer->expires);
    log_verbose("DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer data %x\n", timer->data);
    log_verbose("DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer function %x\n", timer->function);

    // ***** THIS IS WHERE STACK TRACE OCCURS (WHEN CALLED FOR SECOND TIME)
    add_timer(timer);

    log_verbose("DEBUG ADD TIMER: Value of HZ is %d\n", HZ);
    log_verbose("DEBUG ADD TIMER: End of probe\n");

    return 0;
}
```

the stack trace produces
`list_add corruption. prev->next should be next (ffffffff81f76228), but was           (null). (prev=ffffffffa050a3c0).` 
and
`list_add double add: new=ffffffffa050a3c0, prev=ffffffffa050a3c0, next=ffffffff81f76228.`

Looking at the printk statements, it is clear that the add_timer is trying to add the same routine to the linked list. Is this correct?

```
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer expires fffd9cd3
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer data 6c0ac000
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer function **a0508150**
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Value of HZ is 1000
DEBUG ADD TIMER: End of probe
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Starting poll routine with 6c0ad000
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer expires fffd9c7d
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer data 6c0ad000
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer function **a0508150**
```

So my question(s) is(are), how should I configure the timer for multiple instantations of the same driver? (Assuming that is what is happening when multiple boards are inserted into the machine).

full stack trace

```
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Inserting driver into kernel.
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Starting poll routine with 6c0ac000
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer expires fffd9cd3
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer data 6c0ac000
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer function a0508150
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Value of HZ is 1000
DEBUG ADD TIMER: End of probe
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Starting poll routine with 6c0ad000
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer expires fffd9c7d
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer data 6c0ad000
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Timer function a0508150
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 2201 at lib/list_debug.c:33 __list_add+0xa0/0xd0()
list_add corruption. prev->next should be next (ffffffff81f76228), but was           (null). (prev=ffffffffa050a3c0).
Modules linked in: xdma_v7(POE+) xt_CHECKSUM ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast ip6t_rpfilter ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_conntrack ebtable_nat ebtable_broute bridge stp llc ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_nat nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_nat_ipv6 ip6table_mangle ip6table_security ip6table_raw ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack iptable_mangle iptable_security iptable_raw intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal coretemp kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller crc32c_intel eeepc_wmi ghash_clmulni_intel asus_wmi ftdi_sio iTCO_wdt snd_hda_codec sparse_keymap raid0 iTCO_vendor_support
 snd_hda_core rfkill sb_edac ipmi_ssif video mxm_wmi edac_core snd_hwdep mei_me snd_seq snd_seq_device ipmi_msghandler snd_pcm mei acpi_pad tpm_infineon lpc_ich mfd_core snd_timer tpm_tis shpchp tpm snd soundcore i2c_i801 wmi nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace sunrpc ast drm_kms_helper ttm drm igb serio_raw ptp pps_core dca i2c_algo_bit
CPU: 0 PID: 2201 Comm: insmod Tainted: P           OE   4.1.8-100.fc21.x86_64 #1
Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. Z10PE-D8 WS/Z10PE-D8 WS, BIOS 1001 03/17/2015
 0000000000000000 00000000ec73155d ffff880457123928 ffffffff81792065
 0000000000000000 ffff880457123980 ffff880457123968 ffffffff810a163a
 0000000000000246 ffffffffa050a3c0 ffffffff81f76228 ffffffffa050a3c0
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff81792065>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
 [<ffffffff810a163a>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8a/0xc0
 [<ffffffff810a16c5>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
 [<ffffffff810f8250>] ? vprintk_emit+0x3b0/0x560
 [<ffffffff813c7c30>] __list_add+0xa0/0xd0
 [<ffffffff81108412>] __internal_add_timer+0xb2/0x130
 [<ffffffff811084bf>] internal_add_timer+0x2f/0xb0
 [<ffffffff8110a1ca>] mod_timer+0x12a/0x210
 [<ffffffff8110a2c8>] add_timer+0x18/0x30
 [<ffffffffa050810f>] dat_probe+0xbf/0x100 [xdma_v7]
 [<ffffffff813f6da5>] local_pci_probe+0x45/0xa0
 [<ffffffff812a8da2>] ? sysfs_do_create_link_sd.isra.2+0x72/0xc0
 [<ffffffff813f8109>] pci_device_probe+0xf9/0x150
 [<ffffffff814e7e59>] driver_probe_device+0x209/0x4b0
 [<ffffffff814e81db>] __driver_attach+0x9b/0xa0
 [<ffffffff814e8140>] ? __device_attach+0x40/0x40
 [<ffffffff814e5973>] bus_for_each_dev+0x73/0xc0
 [<ffffffff814e772e>] driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
 [<ffffffff814e72e0>] bus_add_driver+0x180/0x250
 [<ffffffffa000a000>] ? 0xffffffffa000a000
 [<ffffffff814e89d4>] driver_register+0x64/0xf0
 [<ffffffff813f662c>] __pci_register_driver+0x4c/0x50
 [<ffffffffa000a02c>] dat_init+0x2c/0x1000 [xdma_v7]
 [<ffffffff81002148>] do_one_initcall+0xd8/0x210
 [<ffffffff812094f9>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x1a9/0x230
 [<ffffffff817911bc>] ? do_init_module+0x28/0x1cc
 [<ffffffff817911f5>] do_init_module+0x61/0x1cc
 [<ffffffff811270bb>] load_module+0x20db/0x2550
 [<ffffffff81122990>] ? store_uevent+0x70/0x70
 [<ffffffff8122e860>] ? kernel_read+0x50/0x80
 [<ffffffff81127766>] SyS_finit_module+0xa6/0xe0
 [<ffffffff8179892e>] system_call_fastpath+0x12/0x71
---[ end trace 340e5d7ba2d89081 ]---
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 2201 at lib/list_debug.c:36 __list_add+0xcb/0xd0()
list_add double add: new=ffffffffa050a3c0, prev=ffffffffa050a3c0, next=ffffffff81f76228.
Modules linked in: xdma_v7(POE+) xt_CHECKSUM ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast ip6t_rpfilter ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_conntrack ebtable_nat ebtable_broute bridge stp llc ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_nat nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_nat_ipv6 ip6table_mangle ip6table_security ip6table_raw ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack iptable_mangle iptable_security iptable_raw intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal coretemp kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller crc32c_intel eeepc_wmi ghash_clmulni_intel asus_wmi ftdi_sio iTCO_wdt snd_hda_codec sparse_keymap raid0 iTCO_vendor_support
 snd_hda_core rfkill sb_edac ipmi_ssif video mxm_wmi edac_core snd_hwdep mei_me snd_seq snd_seq_device ipmi_msghandler snd_pcm mei acpi_pad tpm_infineon lpc_ich mfd_core snd_timer tpm_tis shpchp tpm snd soundcore i2c_i801 wmi nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace sunrpc ast drm_kms_helper ttm drm igb serio_raw ptp pps_core dca i2c_algo_bit
CPU: 0 PID: 2201 Comm: insmod Tainted: P        W  OE   4.1.8-100.fc21.x86_64 #1
Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. Z10PE-D8 WS/Z10PE-D8 WS, BIOS 1001 03/17/2015
 0000000000000000 00000000ec73155d ffff880457123928 ffffffff81792065
 0000000000000000 ffff880457123980 ffff880457123968 ffffffff810a163a
 0000000000000246 ffffffffa050a3c0 ffffffff81f76228 ffffffffa050a3c0
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff81792065>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
 [<ffffffff810a163a>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8a/0xc0
 [<ffffffff810a16c5>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
 [<ffffffff810f8250>] ? vprintk_emit+0x3b0/0x560
 [<ffffffff813c7c5b>] __list_add+0xcb/0xd0
 [<ffffffff81108412>] __internal_add_timer+0xb2/0x130
 [<ffffffff811084bf>] internal_add_timer+0x2f/0xb0
 [<ffffffff8110a1ca>] mod_timer+0x12a/0x210
 [<ffffffff8110a2c8>] add_timer+0x18/0x30
 [<ffffffffa050810f>] dat_probe+0xbf/0x100 [xdma_v7]
 [<ffffffff813f6da5>] local_pci_probe+0x45/0xa0
 [<ffffffff812a8da2>] ? sysfs_do_create_link_sd.isra.2+0x72/0xc0
 [<ffffffff813f8109>] pci_device_probe+0xf9/0x150
 [<ffffffff814e7e59>] driver_probe_device+0x209/0x4b0
 [<ffffffff814e81db>] __driver_attach+0x9b/0xa0
 [<ffffffff814e8140>] ? __device_attach+0x40/0x40
 [<ffffffff814e5973>] bus_for_each_dev+0x73/0xc0
 [<ffffffff814e772e>] driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
 [<ffffffff814e72e0>] bus_add_driver+0x180/0x250
 [<ffffffffa000a000>] ? 0xffffffffa000a000
 [<ffffffff814e89d4>] driver_register+0x64/0xf0
 [<ffffffff813f662c>] __pci_register_driver+0x4c/0x50
 [<ffffffffa000a02c>] dat_init+0x2c/0x1000 [xdma_v7]
 [<ffffffff81002148>] do_one_initcall+0xd8/0x210
 [<ffffffff812094f9>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x1a9/0x230
 [<ffffffff817911bc>] ? do_init_module+0x28/0x1cc
 [<ffffffff817911f5>] do_init_module+0x61/0x1cc
 [<ffffffff811270bb>] load_module+0x20db/0x2550
 [<ffffffff81122990>] ? store_uevent+0x70/0x70
 [<ffffffff8122e860>] ? kernel_read+0x50/0x80
 [<ffffffff81127766>] SyS_finit_module+0xa6/0xe0
 [<ffffffff8179892e>] system_call_fastpath+0x12/0x71
---[ end trace 340e5d7ba2d89082 ]---
DEBUG ADD TIMER: Value of HZ is 1000
DEBUG ADD TIMER: End of probe
```

Comment: `init_timer`, like many other *initialization* functions, is **not thread-safe** (it initializes lock object, which will be used in others, thread-safe operations on the timer). Move `init_timer` to module's initialization code, and then use `mod_timer` for modify timeout instead of `add_timer`.

Comment: Many thanks, however after modifying my code and trying this out, I am not sure it is the solution. It became apparent that __init is only called once when the module is inserted, but we need two instances of the timer, one for each of the active modules.

Comment: So you need **own instance** of the timer for each module, like @Ian Abbott answers.

Comment: Yes.. Somehow his post got overlooked when posting my initial reply - and I didn't get any emails for the updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the second call to `dat_probe` is clobbering the `poll_timer` variable that was initialized and queued by the first call to `dat_probe`. You are clobbering the pointers in the kernel's timer list.

You need to get rid of the `poll_timer` variable and give each device its own dynamically allocated private data structure containing its own `struct timer_list` member. Call `pci_set_drvdata` to set the private data pointer for the PCI device. The other PCI driver functions can call `pci_get_drvdata` to retrieve that pointer.